# awk gives the following error

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, sed, awk

"awk: Function systime is not defined."

but systime is a built in command

Comment: Could you show us the whole command that you are using? It is hard to guage what you are looking for with such limited info.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Solaris, `/usr/bin/awk` is by default a link to `/usr/bin/oawk`, which does not recognize `systime` as a built in (or a lot of other extensions over the 7th Edition AWK).  Either relink `/usr/bin/awk` to `/usr/bin/nawk` or use `nawk` directly, or get GNU Awk (`gawk`) installed and use that.

Other Unix systems like HP-UX, AIX may have similar issues.  MacOS X (and, by inference, BSD) install a non-GNU, non-extended version of `awk` (thanks for the correction, DMcKee). Linux does not; it uses GNU Awk as the main/only `awk`.  Of course, GNU Awk can easily be installed on any of these systems.

Comment: Correction: at least for 10.4 and 10.5 Mac OS does *not* use gawk by default. It is easily installed using fink (or presumably macports).

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a matter of awk "flavor".

GAWK (gnu awk) includes systime(), but maybe the version you are using does not...

Unless systime calls are meant to keep track of time differences within the awk script itself, a trick to circumvent the lack of awk systime() function would be to pass the value of this system variable as a variable on the awk command line.

Answer (score 3):

As an example, on my system both `gawk` and `mawk` are installed.

```
echo |mawk '{print systime()}'
```

produces:

```
mawk: line 2: function systime never defined
```

while

```
echo |gawk '{print systime()}'
```

produces:

```
1252953754
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to get the time stamp

```
nawk '{system("date +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S|tr -d \"\n\"");print" " $0 } '
```