# awk: passing variables from bash

Tags: awk

I am getting syntax errors with the following code. Is there an awk version that does not support the "-v" option or am I missing something? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
f_name="crap.stat" 
S_Date="2012-02-10"
E_Date="2012-02-13"

awk -F "\t" -v s_date="$S_Date" -v e_date="$E_Date" 'BEGIN {print s_date,e_date}' $f_name
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: what is your awk version? and system config?

Comment: please check `awk --version` and `which bash` ?

Comment: ran awk --version and it is still running, strange? I am using solaris 10 x86

Comment: it worked after I used gawk (version 4.0.0) instead of awk. Thanks all.

Comment: gawk and awk are same if you are in GNU linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [awk gives the following error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423155/awk-gives-the-following-error)

Answer (score 1):

Your code completely works on my awk (GNU Awk 3.1.6).

There is another way though, If you export your variables you can use it in `ENVIRON` array

```
$ export f_name="crap.stat"
$ awk '{ print ENVIRON["f_name"] }' anyfile
crap.stat
```

Comment: Thanks but, I get the error even without an input file: awk -v sdate="$S_Date" 'BEGIN {print sdate}'

Comment: On awks that don't support `-v sdate=value '...'`, you can instead do this: `awk '...' sdate=value`. The downside is that the assignment won't be visible inside a `BEGIN {...}` rule, but only once awk begins processing its ARGVs.

Answer (score 1):

The default `awk` program on Solaris 10 (aka `oawk`) does not seem to support the `-v` option; the alternative `nawk` program does support it.  Some people switch the name `awk` so it is a link to `nawk`, so you can't readily predict which you'll find as `awk`.

The `awk` programs on HP-UX 11.x, AIX 6.x and Mac OS X (10.7.x) all support the `-v` notation, which isn't very surprising since [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) expects support for `-v`.